# Suggestions on the integration of Dirac $\delta$-function

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals, contour-integration, complex-integration

I came across a really different integral that relates the product of a function and the delta Dirac written as follows

$\displaystyle\int \delta(y-f(x,m))\frac{1}{f(x,m)}dx$

Based on your broad experience, I ask for some suggestions for integration techniques that allow solving this particular integral.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276583/dirac-delta-function-of-a-function

Comment: Hi @Simon. I hope you are doing well. I thank you for the post,  it helps, but does not solve it. I have asked this question, because I have no ideia how to solve this particular type of integral.

Comment: Then you have to tell us something about the function $f$. For a general function, the linked answer is all I can tell you. You will have to find the values of $x$ such that $y-f(x,m)=0$. And at those values find the derivative (w.r.t. $x$) of $y-f(x,m)$.

Comment: @Simon. Well, the function $f(x,m)$, in most of the applications that I am interested in, can be written as polynomials that relate both $x$ and $m$. For instance, $f(x,m)=m-x^{2}$.

Comment: First, the Dirac Delta is NOT a function; it is a distribution.  Second, this is NOT an integral;  it is a linear functional.

Answer (score 0):

For the example $f(x,m)=m-x^2$, you can use the formula as in [Dirac Delta Function of a Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276583/dirac-delta-function-of-a-function) .

Define $g(x)=y-f(x,m)$.

- If $m>y$, the function $g$ has two zeros, namely $x_{1,2}=\pm\sqrt{m-y}$. Therefore the integral is:
  \begin{align}
  \int \delta(y-f(x,m))\frac{1}{f(x,m)}dx
  &= \frac{1}{f(x_1,m)}\frac{1}{|g'(x_1)|}+\frac{1}{f(x_2,m)}\frac{1} {|g'(x_2)|}
  \end{align}
- if $m<y$, the function $g$ has no zeros, so the integral is zero.
- if $m=y$, the function has a double zero at $x=0$, and things get somewhat complicated. Im not going into details here, but maybe look at [Dirac delta of a function with zero derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/635407/dirac-delta-of-a-function-with-zero-derivative) for some ideas.

This method is correct for any function $f$.

Important note: you do need to determine how many roots the function $g$ has, but you may not need to compute them explicitly. For example you can easily see that
\begin{align}
f(x_1,m)=y-g(x_1)=y
\end{align}
without knowing what the precise value of $x_1$ is. Similar tricks might be possible for the $g'(x_i)$ term. This of course depends on the function $f$, but with polynomials, your chances are somewhat good that you can simplify it somewhat.